# How to config git to use PAT token in GitHub actions checkout

Tags: github-actions, rust-cargo, git-config

I need to check out a private repo during a GitHub Actions workflow. I am using the checkout action, and following its [README](https://github.com/actions/checkout):

1. I created a service account, i.e. a separate GitHub account just for GitHub Actions workflow.
2. I created a PAT (Personal Access Token) for the service account, with permission to access the private repo and the current workflow repo.
3. I created a secret to store the PAT token.

Now, when I just do the following, it does not work:

```yaml
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    token: ${{secrets.MY_TOKEN}}
```

it seems that I did not config `git` properly to allow it use the token. My question is: should I or how do I configure `git config` to use token in the above step?

The private repo is a dependency of the main repo. Both repos are Rust programs, using Cargo, so I am trying to use the same service account to check out the main repo first. Then cargo will check out the private repo.

Comment: Regarding git config, I was wondering if I should do anything with `credential helper` so that git will use the token?

Comment: Hi, I recently created an action that could be a workaround to your problem, if you want to take a look: [clone-github-repo-action](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/clone-github-repo-action). Basically, this action allows you to clone a public or private repo in your workflow using your PAT, then you'll have access to the repository files and folders to perform your operations.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the actions/checkout documentation](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout#checkout-multiple-repos-private), you need to add the `repository input` as well for private repositories:

It should look like the following on your workflow `.yml` file:

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    path: main

- name: Checkout private repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
     repository: your-private/repo_name
     token: ${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}
```

You shouldn't need to configure anything else regarding `git`

Except if you need a specific `path`, in that case you need to inform it as input as well:

```
- name: Checkout private repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
     repository: your-private/repo_name
     token: ${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}
     path: path-to-directory
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work. I didn't use `repository` because the private repo is a dependency, not a side-by-side repo with the main repo. I wanted to use the same account to pull the main repo, and it will also pull the dependency.  Btw, both repo are Rust programs using Cargo.

Comment: Sorry I found out that I didn't ask the right question. The Checkout was actually successful always, but `cargo build` failed as the build is a different action, and does not use the token provided to `checkout` action. I found the solution now to solve that now.

Comment: Great! Share the solution please, I'm curious now :D

Comment: The solution was to use `fusion-engineering/setup-git-credentials@v2`. Then `cargo build` will be able to use the credentials to pull the dependent private repo.

Answer (score 2):

If it's about rust cargo accessing github using token, then a working option could be to add a step for setting token and force https access:

```
- name: Set github url and credentials
  run: |
    /usr/bin/git config --global --add url."https://${{ secrets.GH_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github".insteadOf ssh://git@github
    /usr/bin/git config --global --add url."https://${{ secrets.GH_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github".insteadOf https://github
    /usr/bin/git config --global --add url."https://${{ secrets.GH_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github".insteadOf git@github
```