# Push from GitHub Actions did not trigger a workflow

Tags: github-actions

I have 2 workflows:

1. Running on pushes to `dev`, that at the end pushes to `main`:

   ```
   name: Development Deploy
   concurrency: on-dev-push

   on:
     push:
       branches:
         - dev

   jobs:
     //***//
     promote-to-staging:
       needs:
         - smoke-tests
       name: Promote to staging
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       timeout-minutes: 2
       steps:
         - uses: actions/checkout@master
           with:
             fetch-depth: 0

         - name: Merge changes into main
           run: |
             git remote set-url origin https://botty-mc-bot:${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PAT }}@github.com/***/***.git

             git config --local user.email "botty-mc-bot@stuff.com"
             git config --local user.name "Botty McBot"

             git switch main
             git merge origin/dev -m "ci: stage deploy"

             git push origin main
   ```
2. Running on pushes to `main`

   ```
   name: Staging Deploy
   concurrency: on-main-push

   on:
     push:
       branches:
         - main

   jobs:
     /***/
   ```

I just merged a PR into `dev`, I can see the last job (`promote-to-staging`) completed. I can see the commits on `main`, but the 2nd workflow didn't run. Any ideas why?

Comment: [_"events triggered by the `GITHUB_TOKEN` ... will not create a new workflow run"_](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication)

Comment: This is not a `GITHUB_TOKEN` but a `PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN` of a machine account (actual GitHub user)

Comment: Where do you set the PAT?

Comment: Oh, I see. You can also set it on checkout, which persists the credentials.

Comment: Any chance that concurrency intefered?

Comment: Concurrency should have not been an issue here

Comment: Did you try setting the `token` input in the `actions/checkout` action step, with the PAT? The token used for the push might not be the same that you set for the remote. Example: `token: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PAT }}`

Comment: @GuiFalourd that worked. thanks a bunch. If you add this as an answer I'll tick it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to config git to use PAT token in GitHub actions checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030607/how-to-config-git-to-use-pat-token-in-github-actions-checkout)

Answer (score 0):

The github token used for the `git push` operation is not be the same that you set for the `git remote` operation.

To guarantee using the same token for all the job operations, you can add this PAT as token input to the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout).

In your case:

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PAT }}
```